# How forward org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.Logger to my logs

Tags: java, logging, mqtt, aws-iot, levels

I use AWS IoT library in my tomcat9 service

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to print all logs of org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.Logger into my log file/console? All trace logs like this:

```
//@TRACE 603=clearState
log.fine(CLASS_NAME, methodName,">");
```

How can I do this?

**UPDATE - My code:**

**Service.java**

```
static {
  MyManager manager = new MyManager();
}
```

**MyManager.java**

```
public MyManager() {
  iotClient = new AWSIotMqttClient(Configuration.IOT_CLIENT_ENDPOINT,
                    deviceId,
                    keyStore,
                    keystorePass);
    
  iotClient.setKeepAliveInterval(30000); //30 seconds       
  iotClient.connect();
}
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">${sys:catalina.base}/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
 
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/app-info.log" filePattern="${basePath}/app-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
 
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="info" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**For example logs that I'm interesting:**
Due to this line `iotClient.setKeepAliveInterval(30000)`, iot client sends ping request every 30 seconds in `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState#checkForActivity` and I would like to get all logs during this process.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the logging library you are using in your application ?

Comment: My service is using Log4j2

Comment: Is it with SL4J or plain Log4j2 ?

Comment: it is with SL4J

Answer (score 0):

You are using Log4j2 with SL4J but by default Eclipse MQTT uses [JUL logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) so you would need [log4j-jul](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jul) dependency too.
Also you might need following property to be set `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager`
Once you have these, you can configure logging level for appropriate package- for e.g.g

```
<Logger name="org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3"  level="FINE" />
```

On my test program when I configure as above - I can see trace/fine level logs as below

```
2021-03-01 13:05:45,825 SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)
2021-03-01 13:05:46,138 SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)

***********************************************************************
Message Arrived at Time: 2021-03-01 13:05:46.137  Topic: testTopic  Message: retain
***********************************************************************
```

Below is my Log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    
    <Logger name="org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3"  level="FINE" />
    
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**UPDATE**: Although my code does not uses AWS IOT library but I am connecting to a test MQTT server from my code ( which uses MQTT client library) and when I pass keep-alive interval to be 2 sec and put the logs on trace/fine - I can see the ping message in the logs as below

```
2021-03-05 00:19:08,782 MQTT Ping: demoClient1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)
2021-03-05 00:19:10,692 SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)
2021-03-05 00:19:10,802 MQTT Ping: demoClient1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)
2021-03-05 00:19:12,712 SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)
2021-03-05 00:19:12,812 MQTT Ping: demoClient1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)
2021-03-05 00:19:14,702 SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)
2021-03-05 00:19:14,822 MQTT Ping: demoClient1 TRACE Call to LogManager.getLogger(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token)
```

Comment: 1. Where do I need to add this: <Logger name="org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3"  level="FINE" />? 2. For this Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager can I use System.setProperty?

Comment: This should be in your logging configuration file - generally named log4j2.xml and it is put in classpath. For maven based projects - generally the location is src/main/resources. For manager you can pass it in java_opts in your program or tomcat startup script. You can try setting via System.setProperty as well but you would need to try that.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Can you publish your log4j2.xml? I'm using tomcat with log4j2.

Comment: Can you post your minimum possible workable code at github ( removing any extra or sensitive code). Since your problem is just related to logging you should be able to do so.

Comment: @Rougher - see my updated answer where ping logs coming out of mqtt client library are getting printed in console.